# Is it possible to update the two different databases(oracle,sybase) the single hibernate configuration file?

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to update the two different databases(oracle,sybase) using the single hibernate configuration file?

Also I want the first transaction to be roll backed if the second transaction failed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to connect to multiple databases from a single `SessionFactory`, no.

You can have multiple `SessionFactory` instances though, configured separately.

> I want the first transaction to be roll backed if the second transaction failed. Is it possible?

If you want to robustly coordinate the transactions you need to look into using a distributed transaction. Read: [JTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API). You will need to have some sort of transaction manager configured, which can be a pain to set up and adds a lot of complexity.

If you don't need consistency guarantees you could look into using something like Spring's `TransactionSynchronization`. It's going to be messy though. It's always going to come down to "commit one then the other".

Have you considered running two tasks and using something like JMS to coordinate? This might be a cleaner solution.